# How to Develop An Application That Uses a C File from Android Source Code

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk

I want to develop an Android application that uses a c file from Android source code. I know I can use NDK for using C/C++ files. But, I don't know whether I can use a c file from Android source or not. I want to use it because I want to use a function of it. Is it possible to use system functions with java application?

Answer (score 0):

As far as incorporating C code directly in Android Dalvik code, I'm not sure that's possible without compiling through the NDK and including it as a library. This may help, in particular the 3rd demo (about 36 mins in) which shows implementing an algorithm in C and calling it from Android Dalvik code.

http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/HowToCodeThee.html

Comment: I can compile that file through NDK and include it as a library. But, is it enough? With compiling just one file from Android source code can I make the system do the thing I want?